# Buying a domain through azure fails

Tags: azure

So I created a Free trial account with Azure. I have Developed an MCV 5 web application, hosted it on the xxxx.azurewebsites.net and I am happy. I want to now buy a Custom domain so that the web application can run from there, but it fails to order the domain ? Why ??

I have upgraded to Pay-as-you-go and have changed from Free to Shared, which saying it allows custom domains. Yet... still failing.

Am I missing something? Or need to change something to allow purchasing of a Custom domain ?

Comment: If you experience a problem using the services of Company X then you should probably first consult the Service Desk of Company X before posting here...

Comment: I contacted Company X and there is no number for Company X in my country. Thats why I posted here.

Comment: You say 'it fails', without any detail or what happens. So little we can do here. In the mean time I found this guide: https://azure.microsoft.com/nl-nl/documentation/articles/custom-dns-web-site-buydomains-web-app/ and also a general support page: https://portal.azure.com/#blade/Microsoft_Azure_Support/HelpAndSupportBlade

Comment: Have you ever bought a custom domain through azure or know why this happens ? Thanks for the URL in any case. I have gone through that URL before(the english version), but it does not say anything about if buying a domain fails. I have sent my issue through a contact page on the Azure Web site before posting this, so I hope they contact me and can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got this sorted. This is something I havnt seen people explaining, so those that are new with Azure(Like me), wont know this.

Even if you change the subscription to Pay-As-You_Go, it is still under the Free Trial, so you are not able to buy a custom domain. You will need to get in contact with the Azure team in your country(There is none here in South Africa, so i needed to go to their contact form on the azure site and submit it). An Azure team member phoned me from Microsoft India and converted my account to Pay-as-you-go, which meant I lost my free credit. Only THEN, could I buy a custom domain.

Hope this helps someone else.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, it can be repro in the free trail account.
After setup in the Azure Portal then you will get 200$ for free trail account.

In my option, it is just valid for the Azure resource. You can get the detail info from the link https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/free/?b=16.36.

It may not be used for 3rd product. Buy domain is just the function the Azure integrated with GoDaddy. So when you try to buy the custom domain it will be failed.

If you try to use custom domain  ,please refer to  [Configure a custom domain name in Azure App Service](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-godaddy-custom-domain-name/) (Purchased directly from GoDaddy)